# Play2 Scala - Json format with circular dependency

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have two classes, and each of them contains the other:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class Param(name: String,
                 data: ParamData)
case class ParamData(`type`: String,
                     value: String,
                     options: Option[List[Param]])

implicit val paramDataJsonFormat = Json.format[ParamData]
implicit val paramJsonFormat = Json.format[Param]
```

when I define the Json format I get a compilation error:

> Error:(110, 51) No implicit format for List[Param]] available.
>
> implicit val paramJsonFormat = Json.format[Param]

If I change the order of the implicits I get the same error on the other line:

> Error:(110, 51) No implicit format for List[ParamData]] available.
>
> implicit val paramDataJsonFormat = Json.format[ParamData]

How can I solve this?

Comment: How are you gonna instantiate one of this classes? The only way I see would be to add a `null` in one of the two or an empty list in `ParamData`.

Comment: @EndeNeu You're right. The `options` member of `ParamData` is optional. I'll edit the question. Thanks

Comment: That doesn't change what I was hinting to though, usually when I end up with cyclic references it's because there's a flaw in my design, in your case even if you use options, you still can have a `None` or a `Some` with an empty list, as you can see there's much difference.

Comment: Suppose you have to model a menu item with an object. A menu item has a name and (optionally) a series of sub-items. How would you model it avoiding cyclic references?

Comment: I admit I've never encountered this situation but it makes sense. You need then to write your own format (`new Format[Param] {...} `), and manually handle the case where there is a `None`, a `Some` and empty and non empty list. you cannot use the macro expansion for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution in the [Play official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Recursive-Types). There is a specific section regarding recursive types I was missing.

Comment: Maybe it helps somebody https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55255292/play-json-serialize-deserialize-mutual-recursive/55256753#55256753